# Get list of available servers in SQL server group

Tags: sql, vb.net

How can I extract the list of available SQL servers in an SQL server group? I'm planning to put that list in a combo box in VB.NET.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way I knew to do it was using the command line:

```
osql -L
```

But I found the below article which seems to solve your specific goal filling a combobox:

http://www.sqldbatips.com/showarticle.asp?ID=45

Answer (score 5):

If you didn't want to be tied to SQL SMO, which is what [Ben's article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/147680/7444103) uses, you can do something like this to discover all SQL servers on your network:

```vb
Private Sub cmbServer_DropDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbServer.DropDown
    Dim oTable As Data.DataTable
    Dim lstServers As List(Of String)
    Try
        If cmbServer.Items.Count = 0 Then
            System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.WaitCursor
            oTable = System.Data.Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources

            For Each oRow As DataRow In oTable.Rows
                If oRow("InstanceName").ToString = "" Then
                    cmbServer.Items.Add(oRow("ServerName"))
                Else
                    cmbServer.Items.Add(oRow("ServerName").ToString & "\" & oRow("InstanceName").ToString)
                End If
            Next oRow
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        ErrHandler("frmLogin", "cmbServer_DropDown", ex.Source, ex.Message, Ex.InnerException)
    Finally
        System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default

        If oTable IsNot Nothing Then
            oTable.Dispose()
        End If
    End Try
End Sub
```

The [SqlDataSourceEnumerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sql.sqldatasourceenumerator) class is nice because it gives you SQL server discovery right out of the 2.0 framework.

Answer (score 0):

In C# I've used calls to odbc32.dll

For example:

```
[DllImport("odbc32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]

private static extern short SQLBrowseConnect(
IntPtr hconn, StringBuilder inString,
short inStringLength, StringBuilder outString, short outStringLength, out short 
outLengthNeeded);
```

Documentation for that function is on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130926.aspx)